# Javascript: Delete conflict from two equal script instance

Tags: javascript, html, scroller

i make a simple scroller but when i create the second scrooler, the first stop working, the code is here http://jsfiddle.net/3aZLE/3/ 
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the functionality into a single method attached to `onload`.

Also, refactor--it's essentially identical code.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `window.onload =` twice.  The 2nd time you do this, you're replacing what you had assigned the first time.